# Удалить из строки определенный текст

Tags: php

Есть строка вида:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, **...show all 12 brand names**when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book

Мне из нее нужно удалить текст который я выделил жирным - `...show all 12 brand names`

но тут нужно учесть то что число после all может быть всегда разное. И слово `names` сливается со следующим словом(следующее слово всегда разное).

Хотелось бы увидеть наиболее гибкое решение.

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Простое решение:

```php
$find = '/...show all [0-9]+ brand names/';
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ...show all 12 brand nameswhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book';

echo preg_replace($find, '', $string);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$string = "
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
    Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
    ...show all 12 brand nameswhen an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
    scrambled it to make a type specimen book
";

echo preg_replace('/[\.]+show all \d+ brand names/', '', $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/SkaHK

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся **[strripos()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strripos.php)**

Сразу найди "...show all ", а затем " brand names". И вырежи все, что меджу этими позициями.

Comment: не совсем понял сути... можно пример на основе моей строки?